# Modeling two many-to-many relationships that have a constraint between them

Tags: django, database-design, django-models, django-rest-framework

In an application I'm writing, I have 3 models: `Player`, `Plan`, and `Coach`.

They are related like so:

- A `Player` can have many `Plan`s, but each `Plan` is related to
  exactly one `Player`.
- A `Plan` can have many `Coach`s and a `Coach`
  can have many `Plan`s. (e.g. `Coach`s might collaborate to come up with a `Plan`s for `Player`s.)

By themselves, the modeling of these two relationships seems pretty clear: the first is a one-to-many relationship, where a `Plan` has a foreign key to a `Player`, and the second is a many-to-many relationship between `Plan` and `Coach`.

However, there's a third softer relationship between these models: A `Coach` coaches many `Player`s, and a `Player` can have many `Coach`s, *but* the set of `Coach`s set of `Player`s will always the set of `Player`s reach-able through all of the `Coach`'s `Plan`s. **This is the relationship I'm not sure how best to model.**

This feels like a `ManyToMany` relationship with a defined `through` model (where `Plan` is the through model), but the fact that `Plans` to `Coaches` is many-to-many messes this up, since the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) seems to cite that the `through` model must have a single `ForeignKey` to each model.

I'm also using Django Rest Framework, and at the end of the day the outcome I want is to be able to include a property `players` on each returned `Coach`. This property would be a JSON array of `Player` ids.

To that end, it seems like it would be possible to define a direct `ManyToMany` between `Coach`s and `Player`s, then override `Serializer#create` and `Serializer#update` for a `Plan`, and simply grab and update the `Player`s on each `Coach` associated with a created or updated `Plan`. I could then just add the `players` field to the `Serializer` for `Coach`s. This does, however, all seem a bit convoluted and overly complex, which makes me suspect that there's a smarter or cleaner way to do this. **Does anyone know of a more standard way to accomplish this?**

Here's the fuller modeling as defined in `Django` in case the above descriptions weren't clear enough:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    pass

class Plan(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='plans') # Can now do Foo.bars
    coaching_team = models.ManyToManyField(Coach)

class Coach(models.Model):
    pass
```

Here's what the models would look like with my proposed, potentially overly complex change:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    pass

class Plan(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, related_name='plans') # Can now do Foo.bars
    coaching_team = models.ManyToManyField(Coach)

class Coach(models.Model):
    players = models.ManyToManyField(Player)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a `Coach's` `Players` are defined to be those associated with her though a `Plan`, then there's nothing additional to model; you already have the information you need.

Just stick with your original modeling. To get the `ids` of all `Players` associated with `coach` you simply do:

```
Player.objects.filter(plans__coaching_team=coach).distinct().values_list("id", flat=True)
```

Comment: Ok, this makes sense for grabbing the set of IDs for use on the backend. Any chance you know how one would serialize this as some sort of custom field in DRF for delivery to the frontend?

Comment: @Chiubaka: Unfortunately not, as I'm not familiar with DRF. I would expect there to be a standard way to serialize an arbitrary queryset, and I see several StackOverflow answers on that subject. You might want to ask a separate question about it if you can't figure it out, since that's far more general than the specific data modeling question here.

Comment: For anyone looking for a way to create a custom field in DRF, take a look at [Serializer Method Field](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). You can pretty much serialize and return anything using one of these fields, including, but not limited to, information about a complicated model relationship.